# How to add a custom menu to Google Spreadsheet using the API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I wrote a Java code that creates new Google spreadsheets and fills them with content using Google spreadsheets API (v4).
I also added manually to one of these files a script that adds a custom menu to the spreadsheet.
Now, I would like my Java code to add this custom menu script automatically to each file it generates, but I don't find the way to do it...

I read that I can create the spreadsheet from a template, but didn't find code sample of how to do it + I didn't succeed to define my own template because we are not using a G-Suite user...

I will really appreciate any help with it.

This is the script (if it matters):

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('DEEP')
      .addItem('Save to DB', 'showurl')
       .addToUi();
}


function showurl() {
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName();

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight('60').setWidth('150');
  app.setTitle("Save with qualifier "+ name);

  var panel = app.createPopupPanel()


  var time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm");

  var link = app.createAnchor('Save It!', 'http://localhost:8081/miner/fetcher/updateGenericGoogleSheetData/sheetTitle/'+name+'/time/'+time);

  panel.add(link);
  app.add(panel);
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
}
```

Thanks a lot  :)

Comment: In Google Sheets when a spreadsheet is copied which has a script in it the script also gets copied. So rather than using the Sheets API  to create a blank spreadsheet you can use the Drive API to copy your master spreadsheet, which has the script included, and then populate with data

Comment: I'll try that - thanks :)